# Multiple Pull Request Templates in Mono repo

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a github single repo (mono repo) that looks like the following:

```
 /
  - .github
  - docs
  - web
  - mobile
```

**Question:**

I want to create a pull request template only for `web` but not for other folders. Is it possible to achieve it on github?

My `pull_request_template.md`:

```
<!--- Provide a general summary of your changes in the Title above -->

## Description
<!--- Describe your changes in detail -->

## Motivation and Context
<!--- Why is this change required? What problem does it solve? -->
<!--- If it fixes an open issue, please link to the issue here. -->

## Web checklist
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using GitHub templates is not useful if u want to have different templates. You can move to another folder, but u have to add to request parameter `&template=my_template.md`

But u can use bash script which will create PR with your own template.
https://github.com/Evleaps/Script-collection/blob/main/make_pr.sh